Using Loom API to upload mp4 videos to Loom Library
Does anyone have any experience of uploading videos to loom using their API? I can see in the documentation that they support recording video using loom and uploading those recorded videos, but not sure if they support uploading your mp4 files.
Thanks in advance.
I tried their documentation https://dev.loom.com/docs/record-sdk/getting-started and recordSDK only lets upload videos that are recorded using loom. I want to upload mp4 videos from my computer to loom.
